# Is it possible to create Chord Diagram using chorddiag without having a squared Matrix (R)?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a Chord diagram using **chorddiag** library in **R**, I have to columns and 400+ rows. After converting it to a Matrix using the `as.matrix` function then trying to plot it with the following code:
 `chorddiag(df, type = "directional", showTicks = F, groupnameFontsize = 14, groupnamePadding = 10, margin = 90)`. I keep getting the following error

> Error in chorddiag(telco_ex, type = "directional", showTicks = F, groupnameFontsize = 14,  : 
>     'data' must be a square matrix.

And I wanted to know is there a way to force it? or is this library created specifically for squared. matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the "type" to "bipartite" and see if that works.